# Uno R3 wouldn't enter DFU mode

Tags: embedded, arduino-uno, atmel, atmega16

I recently bought an uno r3 from sintron. The board features an Atmel Mega16u2 serial interface but when I plug it to the usb port of my laptop, it's not listed as an usb device in the device manager. The L-LED is blinking with ~1Hz (maybe the initial test programm).

So I did some research and came up with this tutorial.
[Reseting the Uno R3](https://nemochronicles.wordpress.com/2014/10/14/reset-the-atmega8u2-atmega16u2-of-your-dead-arduino-mega-uno/)

The tutorial first suggest to put the uno r3 to dfu mode via connecting two given ICSP pins (thus resetting it). Then it should be listed as an unknown usb device in the device manager, but there is nothing there. How can I set it into DFU mode?

I don't have a second arduino at my disposal but a stm32 cortex m4 board. My last chance would be to flash the arduino via ISP. Any suggestions on that?

In advance I tried to install the arduino drivers manually but it gives me a code 10 exception. No success with any of the suggested solutions from the internet.

I would be glad if somebody could help.

Comment: Does any COM device show up? It could be called unknown. Try looking at the list and then unplugging your Arduino and check if anything goes away.

Comment: Even if i let it display hidden devices, there is nothing as a COM port. The computer doesn't even react to the board being plugged in. No sounds, no changes in the device manger. only the LED blinking (so at least it gets power).